# Excel filter function - pick data column based on cell value (header)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to output concatenated email addresses in C5 based on selected category from the pick list.

The questions is, can I filter Table 1 in cell A18 based on selected category in C2? "Table1[Category2]" is currently hard coded. Could this be somehow a dynamically-picked data column?

```
C5:  =TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, B18:B21)
A18: =FILTER(Table1, (Table1[Parties]=B5)*(Table1[Category2]="X"), "")
```

in
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDEX/XMATCH to return the array indicating which rows for column {selected category} are equal to X.

[image]

With Category2 in cell C2, the formula in G10 returns:

```
{FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}
```

This then becomes the second operand in your filter:

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,FILTER(Table1[Email],(Table1[Parties]=$B5)*(INDEX(Table1,,XMATCH($C$2,Table1[#Headers]))="X")))
```

[image]

Comment: Totally right. Thank you. I stumbled upon an article concerning a similar case where this solution was used. Here's the source with details: https://www.contextures.com/exceldynamicfilteredlist.html